# Passenger Error: [ASYNC BUG] thread_timer: select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I recently installed Rails on a cpanel machine using this guide: http://www.cpanel.net/blog/cpanel-whm-admins/2011/07/installing-mod-rails-and-rails-309-on-a-cpanel-machine.html

When I try and navigate to my app, I receive this error from Passenger:

```
The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.
```

Digging into Apache's error logs, the only error I can find related to this is:

```
[ASYNC BUG] thread_timer: select
EBADF

ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-07-31 revision 32789) [x86_64-linux]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out what is causing this? I've scoured the internet but haven't been able to come up with much :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this too. The current Ruby trunk appears to be [incompatible with Passenger](http://fossplanet.com/f14/%5Bruby-core-37727%5D-issue-passenger-ruby-trunk-178194/); you'll have to downgrade to 1.9.2.

Answer (score 5):

Passenger 3.0.10 has a fix for this problem. It will be released soon according to Hongli Lai (http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=714). You can get the fix now by installing directly from the passenger github repository (https://github.com/FooBarWidget/passenger).

Comment: Thanks - Now it works for me. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, and upgraded to passenger 3.0.12